# get variables from object with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a big object in jquery script, and I want extract it (get variables.
I figure that the need to use ".".
Example:

> data.0.name

But in my case this not work.
Attached Images with examples. How i can get "code" variable?[image]

Comment: What if you replace your object with simple array (`[]`)? It looks strange to keep numeric properties in object.

Answer (score 5):

`0` is not a valid identifier, so you need to use index notation:

```
data[0].code
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems weird to have keys as numbers, use bracket notation.

```
data["0"].name
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll reply in-line to `@SLaks`, he is absolutely correct.

If i am not wrong then you have your data something like:-

```
        var data = [
            {
                "code": "Lorem",
                "created": "2012-01-01"
            },
            {
                "code": "Lorem",
                "created": "2012-01-02"
            },
            {
                "code": "Lorem",
                "created": "2012-01-03"
            }
        ];
```

Now if you need to access the data, you can possibly try two alternatives :-

1st using `.each`

```
//If your using .each for Array
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            console.log("1st Param= " + value.code + "| 2nd Param= " + value.created);
        });
```

2nd :- If you manually want to access `using the index` then you could try :-

```
//If you manualy want to access:
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log("1st Param= " + data[i].code + "| 2nd Param= " + data[i].created);
}
```

Just for reference you could copy and paste the HTML file:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var data = [
                {
                    "code": "Lorem",
                    "created": "2012-01-01"
                },
                {
                    "code": "Lorem",
                    "created": "2012-01-02"
                },
                {
                    "code": "Lorem",
                    "created": "2012-01-03"
                }
            ];
            console.log(data);
            //If your using .each for Array
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                console.log("1st Param= " + value.code + "| 2nd Param= " + value.created);
            });
            //If you manualy want to access:
            console.log("----------");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log("1st Param= " + data[i].code + "| 2nd Param= " + data[i].created);
            }


        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

[Update] Didn't notice `@Palash Mondal` reply, which is what i wanted to convey. Which seems correct to me.